# Why is a domain transfer taking "days" of time?

Tags: domains

1. What exactly is happening during a domain transfer? - what is the underlying mechanism
2. In how many places the information is updated?

Comment: Transferring from one registrar to another takes time mostly because of their policies. Some work faster than others. Who are you transffering from and to?

Comment: does the procedure involve manual work? I am transferring to Net4.in from Melbourne-IT (Yahoo Small Biz)